# Как скопировать часть строки от определенного символа и до конца этой строки в VS 2015?

Tags: c, строки, visual-studio-2015

Задача следующая. Мне нужно ввести 2 предложения, второе состоит из 3 слов, и 2 и 3 слова во втором предложении поменять местами.
Вот сам код на чистом Си (!), добавил комментарии:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[100] = "\0", str2[100] = "\0", str3[100] = "\0";
    puts("Vvedite str1: "); gets(str1);
    puts("Vvedite str2: "); gets(str2);
    int i, n = 0, k = 0, h = 0, l = strlen(str2);
    //n - положение первого проблела
    //k - положение второго пробела
    //h - счетчик пробелов
    //l - количество букаф в str2
    for (i = 1; i < l; i++) {
        if (str2[i] == ' ') {
            h++;
            if (h == 1) {
                n = i+1;
            }
            if (h == 2) {
                k = i+1;
            }
        }
    } //цикл поиска положения первого и второго пробела
    printf("\nn = %d, k = %d, h = %d, l = %d", n, k, h, l);
    int y = k - n;
    //y - количество букв во втором слове
    for (i = n + 1; i < k; i++) {
        strcpy_s(str3, y, str2);
    }
    //цикл, копипастирующий второе слово в str3, в котором есть ошибка ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    printf("\n", str3);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Я работаю в среде Visual Studio 2015. И она требует писать некоторые операторы с нижним подчеркиванием и "s" ("_s"). Обычный strcpy использовать нельзя, так как там какая-то фигня с безопасностью. Как я выяснил, strcpy_s имеет свой собственный формат, то есть

```
strcpy_s('куда вставим', 'сколько байт копируем', 'откуда копируем');
```

Но у меня компилятор выводит ошибку.
[image: Ошибка]

Что необходимо исправить для выполнения поставленной задачи (скопировать второе слово  -> вставить его в str3)?

Comment: Так Вам же вроде как ясно написало, что буфер слишком мал. Посмотрите в дебагере, как (и где) Вы выходите за пределы строки. Никто же не угадает, сколько символов Вы вводили в str2 и какой она у Вас длины в итоге. Ну нет здесь экстрасенсов :(

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вы неверно поняли документацию на strcpy_s: второй параметр показывает не **сколько** копировать, а сколько целевой буфер **может принять**. В итоге у вас может получится ситуация, когда y=5, а str2 длиннее 5 символов. То есть буфер не может принять строку и выдается исключение.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, можно все разрулить обычным алгоритмическим способом.

```
//здесь должен быть фрагмент кода от начала до счетчика пробелов
int y = 0; //номер элемента str3
for (i = k; i < l; i++) {
    str3[y] = str2[i];
    y++;
} //копируем 3 слово в пустой массив
str3[y] = ' '; //добавляем пробел
y++;
for (i = n; i < k; i++) {
    str3[y] = str2[i];
    y++;
} //копируем второе слово
y = 0; //обнуляемся
for (i = n; i < l; i++) {
    str2[i] = str3[y];
    y++;
} //начиная от первого пробела, заменяем второе и третье слово на содержимое str3
puts("\n"); puts(str2); //и да, не забывайте использовать puts и gets вместо printf и scanf
//и т.д.
```